# redirect_uri_mismatch error during server authorization for Google Play Games

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-oauth, google-play-games, google-api-client

I am using [play-games-plugin-for-unity](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity) to authenticate my Unity (Android) game with Google Play Games and pass authentication code to my Python (Flask) server.

While client code works well, I am getting `redirect_uri_mismatch` error when sending authentication request from my server (which I am running locally).

---

I have debugged my server code and confirmed that:

- I am getting auth code from the client correctly
- My redirect_uri is set to `postmessage` (default value set by oauth2client)
- I tried removing "Authorized redirect URIs" (which it created by default when I added linked web app to my game in Google Play Games Console).

Although this seems to be a common problem, I failed to find any examples/references to resolve this while using `play-games-plugin-for-unity`. As far as I can tell, I does not seem to send any `redirect_uri`s but I can't tell for sure without rebuilding native Android plugin and trying to debug it. I feel like I am missing something simple here.

Here is my server code:

```py
from oauth2client import client

credentials = client.credentials_from_code(LINKED_WEB_APP_CLIENT_ID,
    LINKED_WEB_APP_CLIENT_SECRET, 
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games'], 
    server_auth_code)
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking through [clientserverskeleton](https://github.com/playgameservices/clientserverskeleton) Java example, I found out that passing **""** (empty string!!) as redirect_uri works:

```py
from oauth2client import client

credentials = client.credentials_from_code(LINKED_WEB_APP_CLIENT_ID,
    LINKED_WEB_APP_CLIENT_SECRET, 
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games'], 
    server_auth_code,
    redirect_uri="")
```